# Trying to write a function that returns true if its parameter is whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not really sure how `/\s/` works. I just need to return `true` if the function parameter is whitespace (space, tab or return) and false if not.

```js
var ch = /\s/
var lett = A

function isWhiteSpace(lett) {
  if (lett.test(ch)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: It's usually rx.test(). Where test() is a member function of the regex object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First, understanding your error

> From your code:
>
> ```
> var ch = /\s/         // you defining a Regex Object containing an expression 
> var lett = "A"        // there is the character or string to test
>
> ... further ...
>
> if (lett.test(ch)) {  // here you'll get an error cause of inversed order of operands
> ```

the javascript function "test" is a part of Regex built-in object and 
need an object of type 'regex'

## > Syntax

> `*regexObj.test(str)*` or litterally
>   `myRegex.test(myString)`

For more infos, read the doc: 
[Using Regex in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Since, `/\s/` is a Regex Object, You should write:

```
ch.test(lett);

// or shortly 

/\s/.test(lett);
```

---

## Secondly, what you expect

```
// let's create a set (or dictionnary) of each characters you 
// want to match like you have enumerated (space, tab or return)
// \s space
// \t tab
// \n return
// ^  if parameter begin by
// $  if parameter finish by
// you can understand that any desired char between ^ and $
// will verify you have only one char into the tested variable

var charsToMatch = /^[\s\t\n]$/

function isBlank(param)
{
    if(charsToMatch.test(param))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// --> or more shortly

// you dont need to use if/else instructions because .test()
// is already returning the statement you want
function isBlank(param) { return charsToMatch.test(param); }
```

## Testing

```
console.log(isBlank("\n"))   // return true
console.log(isBlank("\n\n")) // return false, because too many chars
console.log(isBlank("\t"))   // return true
console.log(isBlank("A"))    // return false
console.log(isBlank(" "))    // return true
console.log(isBlank(""))     // return false, because just empty
```

## Another syntax

> `var charsToMatch = /^[\s\t\n]$/`

it can also be written like that:

> `var charsToMatch = new RegExp("^[\s\t\n]$")`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of syntax errors in your code. It should look like this:

```js
function isWhiteSpace(lett) {
  return /\s/.test(lett);
}

var lett1 = ' ',
    lett2 = '\n',
    lett3 = 'A';
    
console.log(isWhiteSpace(lett1));
console.log(isWhiteSpace(lett2));
console.log(isWhiteSpace(lett3));
```